# Are framework and .NET the same?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, frameworks

I am a little bit confused, what is the difference between framework, ASP.NET, ADO.NET and C#?

Comment: no! framework is a very general term... like fruit. you're asking "are fruit, mango and banana the same". the question is wrong already. Use the search here and at google to look for answers about any of the 4 terms.

Comment: Some how I never get the idea of people telling others to Google around in SO (no offence, mate)....Can't we just give a simple few lines instead. Later, this can help other googlers too, as SO answers seem to be among the top listings.

Comment: Nope, sorryy. A few lines dont help against missing pages of knowledge. A goo basic book on programmin concepts would.

Answer (score 5):

Framework: It is the sub system within the underlying OS and uses services of the underlying OS to complete a task.

Like .NET Framework, you can consider it as a layer on the underlying window OS and gives you the power of the OS (like file system handling, network connections, etc..)

ASP.NET: It is a concept which is useful for developing web based applications. This concept is having other useful concepts like (session, caching, request/reply process)

ADO.NET: This is again a layer within the .NET Framework which is useful for data services  (like opening a connection to numerious databases, reading from databases, writing back to databases) and here the data soucre is not tied to some specific database. You can use numerous data sources like XML, flat files, Oracle, SQL Server, MS Access.

C#: It's a language which make all the above concepts possible and one of the target languages in the .NET platform.

Comment: A framework is not a subsystem in Windows (or any OS, for that matter). A framework is a group of components and classes which you *extend* for your own purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Google ".net". That brings you here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework

Answer (score 1):

This article may help you:

[How to Learn .NET?](http://dotnet-wagon.blogspot.com/2007/05/how-to-lern-dot-net.html)

**.NET Framework:**
[CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime), IL, ildsm.exe, side-by-side execution, GAC, CTS, assembly, metadata, manifest, memory management, etc.

**Any of the .NET Languages (C# or VB.NET):**
Control structures, datatypes, classes, functions, structure, constructor, abstract class, interface, delegate, events, etc.

**ADO.NET:**
ADO Classes- DataSet, DataTable, Data Adapter, Connection, providers, dataview, dataview manager, DataReation, etc.

**ASP.NET/Windows Forms:**
Creating a Form .Menu, controls (TreeView, Datagrid, etc.), event handling, passing data between forms, data binding.

[Diagram](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_mwaQhgbgzWk/RlQ6rbQAr_I/AAAAAAAAAAM/WJHDe3EmVNA/s320/fw.gif)